# Checking for multiple values in object

Tags: javascript

What would be the easiest way to check for undefined, NuLL and "" in this case:

I am receiving an object that can have and of those three states, and it comes in form of:

images[0].url

Images might not exists at all
Images might have url property of null
Images might have property of ""

I was using if(images[0]), but it covers only existence of [0], not deeper.
How can I solve this, without switch statement.

I tried something like this:

```
   if((object.images[0]) || (object.images[0].url)){

} else {

}
```

But if the [0] exists and url does not, then I get this.
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Comment: Although some might disagree, you could consider using `try/catch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error when object. images[0] does not exist.
To avoid this you could have a gradual check like this.

```
 if(object.images && object.images[0] && object.images[0].url){ 
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: I think your original `&&`s were correct.